# mysql_fetch_array and only string array keys

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

When I try to print_r mysql_fetch_array of a sql query, I get this result.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [id] => 1
    [1] => 2011
    [publish_date] => 2011
    [2] => Posted
    [status] => Posted
    [3] => test
    [post_title] => test
    [4] => &nbsp;testy test test testtttttt
    [post_text] => &nbsp;testy test test testtttttt
    [5] => true
    [post_comments] => true
    [6] => 21
    [reviews] => 21
    [7] => 1
    [network_id] => 1
    [8] => 3
    [views] => 3
    [9] => 0
    [comments] => 0
)
```

All I want is only string array keys so how can I convert this result to that?

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [publish_date] => 2011
    [status] => Posted
    [post_title] => test
    [post_text] => &nbsp;testy test test testtttttt
    [post_comments] => true
    [reviews] => 21
    [network_id] => 1
    [views] => 3
    [comments] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 2):

instead of mysql_fetch_array use mysql_fetch_assoc.
thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) function

or

Use second parameter for [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php#refsect1-function.mysql-fetch-array-returnvalues) function: MYSQL_ASSOC