# double results in my array ( mysql_fetch_array )

Tags: php, mysql

Ok i execute this

```
$table = get_personel_table(1);
function get_personel_table($id)
    {
        global $connection;
        $query  = "SELECT * ";
        $query .= "FROM employees ";
        $query .= "WHERE id=" . $id . " ";
        $query .= "ORDER BY id ASC";
        $query_result = mysql_query( $query , $connection );
        confirm_query($query_result);
        $query_result_array = mysql_fetch_array($query_result);
        return $query_result_array; // returns associative array!;
    }
```

and i do foreach

```
foreach($table as $table_var)
{
    echo "<td>" . $table_var . "</td>";
}
```

and by doing so i get double output ...  "1 1   1   1   jordan  jordan  9108121544  9108121544  testEmail   testEmail   testAddress testAddress testCounty  testCounty"

this below is the result of print_r

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [id] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [department_id] => 1
        [2] => jordan
        [name] => jordan
        [3] => 9108121544
        [EGN] => 9108121544
        [4] => testEmail
        [email] => testEmail
        [5] => testAddress
        [address] => testAddress
        [6] => testCounty
        [country] => testCounty
    )
```

The information i have in the database is   id =>1  , department_id => 1 , and so on ... 
My question is why i get double feedback(i don't know how to call it) ,  0 = id , 1 = department_id , 2 = name and so on ..

and when i do foreach( ... ) i get everything doubled.

Comment: Use `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)`. By default, it returns both numeric and column names as indices.  I'll tend to recommend `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to skip the issue anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array and only string array keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440479/mysql-fetch-array-and-only-string-array-keys)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [the manual](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array):

> mysql_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both

By default, `mysql_fetch_array` gives both associative and numeric indexes. You don't want this. You can limit it with the second parameter:

```php
$query_result_array = mysql_fetch_array($query_result, MYSQL_NUM); // numeric keys only
$query_result_array = mysql_fetch_array($query_result, MYSQL_ASSOC); // associative keys only
```

You can also use [`mysql_fetch_row`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_row) to only get numeric keys, or [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) to only get associative keys.

```
$query_result_array = mysql_fetch_row($query_result); // numeric keys only
$query_result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result); // associative keys only
```

Comment: Thank you. I am new to php ( started 1-2 days ago). And again thank you for your fast answer

Comment: changing from mysql_fetch_array to mysql_fetch_row solved my doubling up for a  while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($query))