# mysql query to pull rows and print them as json

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using some php to generate JSON which my mobile app uses for a table view. Currently it's working but it's displaying the content twice.

This is the code i'm using:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `fName`, `lName`, `number`, `postcode`, `lat`, `long` FROM members WHERE `GroupID`='".$GroupID."'");
$members = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$members['members'][] = $row;
}

print json_encode($members);
```

and i'm getting a result like this:

```
 {
     "0":"First Name",
     "fName":"First Name",
     "1":"Last Name",
     "lName":"Last Name",
     "2":"Mobile Number",
     "number":"Mobile Number",
     "3":"PostCode",
     "postcode":"PostCode",
     "4":"Coord",
     "lat":"Coord",
     "5":"Coord2",
     "long":"Coord2"
  },
```

I'm pretty sure that this line is causing the problem:

```
$members['members'][] = $row;
```

But I can't seem to get it to work...

I'm currently using this code as is, but it's meaning the mobile app has to download twice the information from the server, so it isn't ideal.

Comment: You want `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [double results in my array ( mysql\_fetch\_array )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556794/double-results-in-my-array-mysql-fetch-array)

Comment: It's no duplicate, but thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` or you will get both associative and numerically indexed array.